# Getting unique values within two arrays in one document in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following document:

```
{
  userId: 1234,
  contacts: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  conversations: ['a', 'b', 'e'],
}
```

I want to get distinct value from the contacts and conversations array. So for this case, the output should be: `a, b, c, d, e`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [$setUnion](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/#exp._S_setUnion) operator to aggregate values from two arrays:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            userId: 1, 
            values: {
                $setUnion: [
                    '$contacts',
                    '$conversations'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Result:

```
{ "userId" : 1234, "values" : [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" ] }
```

---

UPDATE: For MongoDB 2.4 you can map each document on client side. Define [unique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1584377/470005) function for array. And then simply map each document

```
db.test.find().map(function(doc) {
   return { 
      userId : doc.userId, 
      values : doc.contacts.concat(doc.conversations).unique()
   };
})
```

Note: if there is several documents with same userId you can group them on server side.

Comment: setUnion seems to be new in 2.6. I'm using 2.4. Any other way?